# Method duplicates output

Tags: java, performance, sling

Pretty new to sling and Java so I apologize in advance. But does anybody have any idea why when I'm at the root it's outputting
my path twice? It's odd that it only happens at the absolute root.

```
public static String generateTest(Page page, Page rootPage, String bc) {

    Page parent = page.getParent();

    String bread = ""; 
    bread += (parent != null) ? "<li><a href=" + parent.getPath() + ">" + parent.getTitle() + "</a>" : "";
    bread += "<li>" + "<a href=" + page.getPath() + ">" + page.getTitle() + "</a></li>" + bc;
    return (ifAtRoot(parent , rootPage)) ? breadcrumb : generateTest(parent, rootPage, bread);

}

public static boolean ifAtRoot(Page page, Page root) {
    return (page == null || root.getPath() == page.getPath());
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `root.getPath() == page.getPath()` something is strange here..

Comment: Note that this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915244/java-recursive-function-duplicating-output AFAICS, with the same code formatted differently.

Answer (score 1):

First, `ifAtRoot()` will return true only if `page` is `null` because you cannot compare objects (including strings) using `==`. You should use `.equals()` instead:

```
public static boolean ifAtRoot(Page page, Page root) {
    return (page == null || root.getPath().equals(page.getPath()));
}
```

In your case first call of `ifAtRoot()` returned `false`, so you called it second time recursively passing `brend` that just has been created. The second call creates `brend` again and appends `bc` (that contains previously created brend) to it. The second call of `ifAtRoot()` for your luck returns true. Otherwise you'd enter infinite recursion and finish with `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: Thanks for replying @AlexR. Although I'm a bit confused using .equals instead of == didn't seem to change anything. Also if I was using == instead of .equals() wouldn't that fail altogether. Thanks for the help!